How can I have text inside span and p tags to be read by NVDA screen reader
I am working on a page using react.
My page has an input box, button, span and p elements.
I am checking Ally with NVDA screen reader and hitting Tab key.
I have a scenario where the focus has to move to a span element and p element and also read the text inside the elements.
function Example() {
  const [tile, setTile] = useState(false);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  return (
    <div className="main">
    <input type="text" name="name" value={inputValue} 
    onChange={e => setInputValue(e.target.value)}/>
    <button onClick={() => setTile(true)}>
        Click me
     </button>
      <br/>
      {tile && <span aria-label={`sample label here with ${inputValue}`}>Based on the input here are the options</span>}
      {tile && <div className="tile">
      <p aria-label="sample label here">Hello there!</p>
      <p aria-label="sample label here">Entered input {inputValue}</p>
      </div> }
    </div>
  );
}

I tried with tabIndex=-1 but that's not working.
I tried with tabIndex=0 but that's not a good practice I believe.
Also I want to include entered input in the label that's being read by screen reader.
JSfiddle

Programming-wise, you don’t need to do anything.
Screen readers basically allow reading a web page. Navigation with focus is another navigational mode, used for forms or interactive applications.
NVDA uses the arrow keys to read. NVDA+↓ will start reading from the current position.
This can be the focus, but also the last read item, or the item under the mouse cursor if configured.
h will jump to the next heading, a navigation technique most used by screen reader users. Also users with perfect vision skim headlines to find the part relevant to them.
WebAIM have a good guide on how to evaluate a website’s accessibility with NVDA, specifically reading a web page with NVDA

I noticed some bad practices in the code above that I would like to address here. Maybe they simply were not relevant to the question, but I don’t want to leave inaccessible code as an example.

The <input> absolutely needs a label, best in a <label> element, aria-label is possible as well but less usable.
aria-label or aria-labelledby on <p> or <span> elements doesn’t do anything. It’s providing accessible names to interactive elements and landmarks only.
When providing an accessible name with aria-label or similar, the visible text MUST contain the accessible name

